# echo json_encode with PHP erroring

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Any idea why this is not working:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT cust_name, description from `projects` where project_no = '".$project_no."'") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo json_encode(
                      array("message1" => '".$row['cust_name']."', 
                      "message2" => '".$row['description']."')
                 )
            }
```

This is the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in /admin/customerfilter.php on line 14`

Line 14 is the line starting with "array..."

Thanks :)

Comment: Format your code properly, and you'll see what's wrong...  Always indent and use a syntax-highlighting IDE/editor and you won't have this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "message1" => $row['cust_name'],
    "message2" => $row['description'],
));
```

Don't make things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Thanks! perfect, the last thing i was trying to do was complicate it :) just get it to work!

Answer (score 4):

Too many quotes:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT cust_name, description from `projects` where project_no = '".$project_no."'") or die(mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo json_encode(
                      array("message1" => $row['cust_name'], 
                      "message2" => $row['description'])
                 )
            }
```

Comment: add the missing ; and it's perfect

Comment: I work just the way compiler does. Only fix the first error reported :P